# how can i use pageLoad function in multiple usercontrols

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have 3 usercontrols who in each i used pageLoad function in javascript and those usercontrols are in a page and page has himself pageLoad function. but only pageLoad function of last usercontrol who i registered in page is fired and others not fired

```
<script type="text/javascript">

...
function pageLoad() {
    alert('page load - uc1');
    .....
}
...
```

please help me how to fire all functions

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define javascript function for each control and execute it on Application.Init and PageRequestManager.EndRequest events:

Client side:

```
function controlSpecificPageLoadFunction(){ alert("Hello, pageLoad!"); }
```

Code behind:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    var script = "Sys.Application.add_init(controlSpecificPageLoadFunction); Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(controlSpecificPageLoadFunction)";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "thisControlPageLoad", script, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but when i try to use this, i get this error: 'Sys' is undefined

Comment: Change the RegisterClientScriptBlock to RegisterStartupScript

Comment: yes, its work. of course semicolon at end of script is lost. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a paradigm called unobtrusive JavaScript that has been getting more and more popular. You should read up on it.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/best_practices/separating_behavior.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Basically instead of saying `onload="myfunction()"`, you wire up the handlers in the JS itself...

```
document.getElementById('myElement').addEventListener('click', myfunction)

function myfunction() { ... }
```

In your case, it would be something like

```
document.body.addEventListener('load', myfunction);
```

This has its own pitfalls however. I would strongly recommend using a library like jQuery, MooTools, Dojo or EXT instead of writing JavaScript from scratch.